# Generate a keycloak register link in a spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm securing a web app build with spring boot with the `keycloak-spring-boot-starter` which creates me `/sso/login` and `/sso/logout` urls. But I also would like to provide a link to the keycloak registration page - but there is no `/sso/register` link.

How do I implement this link? I could not find the place in the keycloak-adapter sources where the login/logout resource is implemented so a point to that would maybe enough.

Comment: Keycloak already provides a user registration mechanism: http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_admin/topics/users/user-registration.html

Comment: @XtremeBiker I know, but I would like to have a "deep link" to the registration page, not a link to the login page and the user has to go to the registration page. I think the java-script adapter has this feature - to deep link to the registration page

Comment: You could just point to the registration page  from your application?

Comment: No, without the `code` url parameter I just get an error page

Comment: @dve - Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do this now and would prefer to not try generating a link like this on my own to the keycloak server `/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=my-client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8042%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=38f19c7f-eed9-40d0-8507-f95ef173a6be&login=true&scope=openid`

Comment: @DeanPoulin no I did not figure this out. I failed finding where in the keycloak spring stuff the login link is created. My idea was to create the register and forego password link the same way and provide a pull request

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own register link like below code ;

```
        String nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    String input = nonce + clientId;
    byte[] check = md.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    String hash = Base64Url.encode(check);

    return KeycloakUriBuilder.fromUri(keycloakEndpoint)
                .path("/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/registrations")
                .queryParam("response_type", "code") // Autherization Code Flow
                .queryParam("scope", "openid") // Add additional scopes if needed
                .queryParam("nonce", nonce)
                .queryParam("hash", hash)
                .queryParam("client_id", clientId)
                .queryParam("redirect_uri", "http://sample.javaspringboot.com/" + "redirect/" + redirectUrl).build(realm).toString();
```